# Can I run a vite server and cypress test in a github workflow?

Tags: cypress, github-actions, vite

I am building an application with vite + react and testing it using cypress. I have end to end tests and they only work if the application is running. I tried to put everything into a workflow according to https://learn.cypress.io/tutorials/running-our-tests-with-github-actions but it always fails when waiting for the server to start. Here is the error:[image: cypress error]

As you can see the server properly starts but the workflow fails when waiting on it. Here is my .yml file:

```
name: Cypress Tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        working-directory: ./app
        run: yarn install

      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          working-directory: ./app
          build: yarn build
          start: yarn dev
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:5173'
```

Comment: Visually everything looks correct, to determine if the problem is with the cypress implementation, GHA, or your code I would try manually running `yarn dev` and seeing if you can execute requests against the dev app inside of a step. If that works then cypress is doing something odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered in https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/issues/879

Workaround: start server with `npx vite --host` (server then listens on 0.0.0.0)

Vite documentation reference is
https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host

Comment: Yes I actually opened that issue haha but thanks again!